# Percentage calculation with sql grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, percentage

I'm new to this field, sorry for my inexperience so;

I have category names and different value entries for that category. I want to group the ones with the same name and get the percentage according to the grand total with the results.
In short, "x is what percent of y number?"

The query I want to process ;

```
 select Category_NM as 'Categories',Convert(decimal(10,2),AVG(Payment)) as 'Average' 
 from Islem 
 where Category_Type = 'Gider' 
 group by Category_NM
```

[image: Here is my output]

and I want to like this query

```
select 
   Category_NM,SUM(Payment) odemeler,
   CONVERT(decimal(5,1),  ((select sum(Payment) 
                            from Islem 
                            where Category_Type = 'Gider' 
                            group by Category_NM) / 
                           (select sum(Payment) 
                            from Islem 
                            where Category_Type = 'Gider')) *100)
from Islem 
where Category_Type = 'GİDER'
```

and I take this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What should I do

Answer (score 0):

you have basically twi options.

First, use a joined subselect

```
select 
    i1.Category_NM
    ,SUM(Payment) odemeler
    ,CONVERT(decimal(5,1),  (
                                SUM(i2.sum_pay)
                                / (select sum(Payment) from Islem where Category_Type = 'Gider')
                            ) *100) 
from Islem i1
JOIN (select Category_NM , sum(Payment) sum_pay from Islem where Category_Type = 'Gider' group by Category_NM) i2 ON i1.Category_NM = i2.Category_NM
where i1.Category_Type = 'GİDER'
```

Or get rid of the Group By ion the subselect and only sum up those rows wit the same Category_NM

```
select 
    Category_NM
    ,SUM(Payment) odemeler
    ,CONVERT(decimal(5,1),  (
                                (select sum(Payment) from Islem i2 where Category_Type = 'Gider'  AND i2.Category_NM = i1.Category_NM) 
                                / (select sum(Payment) from Islem where Category_Type = 'Gider')
                            ) *100) 
from Islem i1 where Category_Type = 'GİDER'
```

both query can't produce your error

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Islem (
> Category_NM int,
>   Category_Type VARCHAR(100),
> Payment float
>  );
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Islem VALUES (1,'GİDER',1.2),(1,'GİDER',2.2),(1,'GİDER',3.2),
> (2,'GİDER',1.2),(2,'GİDER',2.2),(2,'GİDER',3.2)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select 
>     Category_NM
>     ,SUM(Payment) odemeler
>     ,CONVERT(decimal(5,1),  (
>                                 (select sum(Payment) from Islem i2 where Category_Type = 'Gider'  AND i2.Category_NM = i1.Category_NM) 
>                                 / (select sum(Payment) from Islem where Category_Type = 'Gider')
>                             ) *100) 
> from Islem i1 where Category_Type = 'GİDER'
> GROUP BY Category_NM
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Category_NM | odemeler | (No column name)
> ----------: | -------: | ---------------:
>           1 |      6.6 |             50.0
>           2 |      6.6 |             50.0
> ```

> ```
> select 
>     i1.Category_NM
>     ,SUM(Payment) odemeler
>     ,CONVERT(decimal(5,1),  (
>                                 SUM(i2.sum_pay)
>                                 / (select sum(Payment) from Islem where Category_Type = 'Gider')
>                             ) *100) 
> from Islem i1
> JOIN (select Category_NM , sum(Payment) sum_pay from Islem where Category_Type = 'Gider' group by Category_NM) i2 ON i1.Category_NM = i2.Category_NM
> where i1.Category_Type = 'GİDER'
> GROUP  BY i1.Category_NM
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Category_NM | odemeler | (No column name)
> ----------: | -------: | ---------------:
>           1 |      6.6 |            150.0
>           2 |      6.6 |            150.0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bcdc74a054bf8d8418f4f1df81e75233)*

Comment: Sorry didn't work

Comment: which database are you using and what is the exact error?

Comment: I use MS SQL , The error is that the subquery returns more than 1 value as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: please add a dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c04ed912ea708a8c25e1f9be2859fe4 with some data, so that i can test it, this shouldn't give that error message

Comment: @zeyteymen it tested my selects in a test databse as you can see in the changed answer, it is as i thought, you can't get the error with either of them